# The requested module does not provide named export for transformAll, THIS_EXPR from @angular/compiler

Tags: angular, migration, angular-compiler, angular-compiler-cli

I am working on a migration project. Need to migrate from angular 7 to angular latest. I see angular/cli 16 is the latest version. Few named exports are not found by the angular compiler for below. I searched in google, I couldn't any alternative way to use these modules. Any suggestions/recommendations to make this workable.

1. error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler/src/output/output_ast' or its corresponding type declarations.

import { THIS_EXPR } from '@angular/compiler/src/output/output_ast';

2. error TS2339: Property 'msSaveBlob' does not exist on type 'Navigator'.  if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveBlob) {
3. error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler/src/render3/r3_ast' or its corresponding type declarations.

import { transformAll } from '@angular/compiler/src/render3/r3_ast';

Couldn't find any alternative way.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.